# Writing language choice to jQuery file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, file-io

I'm currently programming a website that will be in multiple languages and I was wondering if there is an easy way to program the site only once for all languages.

For example, I have a variable called 'lang'. Basically if the user chooses Spanish then I would like the page to load images (or whatever asset) for buttons with Spanish as opposed to English. So for example, by changing the 'lang' variable, an image called 'home_button_eng.jpg' would instead load 'home_button_spa.jpg'.

I am thinking that this would require 'writing' or 'changing' an external document that contains the 'lang' variable which is then loaded by the page.
In other words, user clicks 'spanish' which makes lang='spa' then a new page loads which is connected to that language_choice.js file. The the appropriate content loads up.

Is there a way of doing this? I would much rather do this than duplicate every English page for Spanish.

Answer (score 1):

Certainly you don't want to duplicate any content or code. I would organise all the assets in subfolders based on their language code:

```
content\
    en\
       images\
    sp\
       images\
```

This avoids having duplicate named files in a single folder for each language. When changing the language, you could store a session variable in your dynamic language of choice (Python, PHP, Ruby...) and use it to populate all the content with the correct language code.

Depending on how dynamic your content will be, you could implement it using `.po` and `.mo` internationalisation files and read them in to get your headings, text and so forth, while still implicitly determining the location of the images and other assets based on the language directory alone.

Answer (score 0):

If all your language specific changes have to do with images you can just dynamically load a language specific CSS file.

If you have text as well you'd probably want to make a localization JSON object for each language you support and load that dynamically. The JSON object would contain the element-ids or element-classes with the language specific text or image source, you would iterating over the objects keys with JavaScript and fill-in the language specific data on the elements references in it.